# Dynamic functions into a loops with R

Tags: r, function, loops, dynamic

This function compute the R^2 into a linear regresion corresponding to dp2distance package using welfare database

```
 library(p2distance)
 data <- as.matrix(welfare)
 calculoFactoresPonderacion = function(matriz) {
    m <- dim(matriz)[1]
    n <- dim(matriz)[2]
    vec.results <- numeric()
    for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
        vec.results[i] <- summary(lm(matriz[, i + 1] ~ matriz[, 
            1:i]))$r.squared
     }
     vect1 <- matrix(1, m, 1)
     coefs <- matrix(vec.results, m, n - 1, byrow = TRUE)
     mR.restado <- 1 - coefs
     mFacPond <- cbind(vect1, mR.restado)
    return(mFacPond)
    }
```

I want to compute regresion using splines through splines package but the 
function "**bs**" don't works with "matriz[, 1:i]" if i>1 . More precisely 
in this part:

```
vec.results[i] <- summary(lm(matriz[, i + 1] ~ bs(matriz[, 
            1:i])))$r.squared
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You are extracting the values of `r.squared`, not of the regressions' coefficients. And to use function `bs` you need to tell how many degrees of freedom you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've already resolved the doubt.